# Power BI: Generate a new row by each row row on another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m

In Power BI, I have a table that looks like this:

```
Table 1  
ID | At1   
1  | 1   
2  | 2   
3  | 3   
4  | 4   
5  | 5
```

And another table that looks like this:

```
Table2  
Value  
A  
B  
C  
D
```

I need to create a new table that add "n" times each row of table 1, where "n" would be each row of table 2. Something like this:

```
Table 3  
ID | At1 | Value  
1  | 1   |   A  
1  | 1   |   B  
1  | 1   |   C  
1  | 1   |   D  
2  | 2   |   A  
2  | 2   |   B    
2  | 2   |   C  
2  | 2   |   D  
3  | 3   |   A  
3  | 3   |   B  
3  | 3   |   C  
3  | 3   |   D  
4  | 4   |   A  
4  | 4   |   B  
4  | 4   |   C  
4  | 4   |   D
```

Comment: As a calculated table in DAX or within the query editor?

Comment: Does `CROSSJOIN` work - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/crossjoin-function-dax?

Comment: You can check this as well - https://exceleratorbi.com.au/cross-join-with-power-query/ if it helps

Comment: @stackoverflowusrone thanks... that's what I needed